# How to bind calender selected value to a txt bx

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to create an ajax popup calender. So When the user clicks a image button the calender should pop up and the selected date from the calender should be bind to a text box.

**This is my aspx code:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBxDate" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="75px">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
ImageUrl="~/images/toolbox.gif" />
<asp:PopupControlExtender ID="ImageButton1_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" 
DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" 
PopupControlID="Panel1" Position="Bottom" TargetControlID="ImageButton1">
</asp:PopupControlExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="200px">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" 
onselectionchanged="Calendar1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Panel>
```

**My Code Behind:**

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtBxDate.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString();
}
```

But when I selected a date from the calender, the selected date wasn't binded to the text box. What I am doing wrong here? or how can I fix it?

Comment: Huh... that's odd. The answer is usually setting `AutoPostBack` to true, but no such property exists for the `Calendar` control. Is the page posting back when you change the selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not updating is because `txtBxDate` is outside of the `UpdatePanel`. Either put `txtBxDate` in the update panel with the calendar, or put it in a separate update panel.

**EDIT**

After inspecting your code a little more closely, it looks like you're trying to manually create the functionality that's already built into the AJAX Toolkit `Calendar` control.

See here: [Calendar Sample](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have your `targetcontrolid` and `popupcontrolid` mixed up. I think it should be:

```
PopupControlID="ImageButton1" TargetControlID="txtBxDate"
```

You can get rid of the code-behind setting the selected date on the text field. The calendar extender should take care of that automatically.

Comment: I think you're getting his example confused with the `CalendarExtender`, in which case you would be right. OP is just using the popup to display a regular calendar control. Which in thinking about it makes me wonder why OP doesn't just use the calendar extender, since that's what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: @JamesJohnson yep, you are right, somehow I thought he was using the calendar extender, which is really the tool for this if you are using the AjaxControlToolkit.

Comment: Confused me a bit too at first :)

Comment: @Icarus You were correct I didn't know about ajax. After I looked up on the internet and found calender extender is the easiest one. Thanx for telling me about it. Now I am using the calender extender in my code.

Comment: @Sas Great! :) that's definitely the extender more appropriate for your scenario.